# Poster image in Embed tag

Tags: html

I am using the `<embed>` tag to read a video stream from a server and I need to set a poster image before play this video but I don't know how I set a poster image in `<embed>`.

This is my code:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
     name="video1"
     autoplay="no" loop="yes" width="400" height="300"
     target="http://10.1.0.1:8180/stream?ip=225.1.0.2&port=1234" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whipped this up real quick for you. Should get the job done.

```
<style>
    embed {
        display:none;
    }
    #myPosterImage {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #vidWrapper {
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
    }
</style>

<div id="vidWrapper">
    <img src="poster.jpg" id="myPosterImage"/>
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
         name="video1"
         autoplay="no" loop="yes" width="400" height="300"
         target="http://10.1.0.1:8180/stream?ip=225.1.0.2&port=1234" /> 
</div>


/* import jQuery at top in <head> and at bottom of page have this: */
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#myPosterImage').on('click', function() {
            $('#myPosterImage').hide();
            $('embed').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `embed` element doesn't have a poster attribute. Video does, but looks like you are doing something that video won't support (assumedly anyway). In that case, you'll probably need to use a `img` element on top, that you remove with JS when the video starts playing.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question but I recommend http://code.google.com/p/fbvlc/wiki/FBVLC_API Its a fork of vlc's plugin which works in both IE and other browsers where as vlc requires different embed tags.

It also has more useful javascript events